# Gerar várias amostras a partir de um mesmo vetor

Tags: r

Sou iniciante em R. Estou tentando fazer uma função para gerar o máximo possível de amostras sem repetição de tamanho 4 retiradas de um mesmo vetor. Tentei fazer um loop com o for, mas não sei fazer a função por completo. O vetor de onde quero retirar as amostras segue abaixo e a função que fiz também:

```
y<-c(1,2,4,4,7,7,7,8)
espaco_amostral<-function(x,n){
set.seed(360)
   for(i in x){ 
     amostra<-sample(x,n,replace=F)
   }
 matrix(amostra,,n)
}
espaco_amostral(y,4)
```

A ideia é que as várias amostras fiquem nas linhas da matriz.

Comment: O que significa "gerar o máximo possível de amostras de tamanho 4 retiradas de um mesmo vetor"? Este número é infinito, pois dado o vetor `c(1,2,4,4,7,7,7,8)` do teu exemplo, eu posso gerar as amostras `1, 1, 1, 1`, `1, 1, 1, 1`, `1, 1, 1, 1`... e assim por diante, sem limite. Todas elas tem tamanho 4. Por acaso as amostras têm que ser únicas? Elas podem ter valores repetidos? É preciso definir um pouco melhor o teu problema.

Comment: Esqueci de dizer que seria amostras se repetição. No caso seriam todas as amostras de tamanho quatro que podem ser retiradas do vetor sem repetição. Por exemplo, utilizando um outro vetor x<-(1,2,3,4), as amostras de tamanho dois possíveis sem reposição são: (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4). Consegui esclarecer melhor?

Comment: Sim, agora ficou claro. Dei uma possível solução para o problema logo abaixo.

Comment: Obrigada, ajudou!

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.

Answer (score 4):

Este problema pode ser resolvido com a função `combn`. Basta informar o vetor que possui a tua população (`x`) e o tamanho da amostra a ser gerada (`2`):

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
t(combn(x, m=2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    3    4
```

Como a função `combn` informa as combinações por coluna, precisei transpor o data frame resultante utilizando a função `t`, de modo que a apresentação ficasse por linha.

Para resolver este problema com os teus dados originais, basta rodar o código abaixo:

```
y <- c(1,2,4,4,7,7,7,8)
t(combn(y, m=4))
```